# Code contracts problem

Tags: c#, warnings, code-analysis, code-contracts

Consider the following code :

```
public class RandomClass
{        
    private readonly string randomString;

    public RandomClass(string randomParameter)
    {
        Contract.Requires(randomParameter != null);
        Contract.Ensures(this.randomString != null);

        this.randomString = randomParameter;
    }

    public string RandomMethod()
    {
        return  // CodeContracts: requires unproven: replacement != null
            Regex.Replace(string.Empty, string.Empty, this.randomString);
    }
}
```

This ensures that `randomString` will not be null when `RandomMethod` gets executed. Why does code contracts analysis ignores this fact and throws a `CodeContracts: requires unproven: replacement != null` warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably not so much that the analyzer ignores the fact that it is unable to make the link between the two methods.

The property "field randomString is non-null" is a *class invariant*: it is established at each instance creation, and trivially preserved on each method call because the field is read-only. I urge you to provide one stating just that. It will be easily verified by the analyzer and will provide the hypothesis necessary to prove that `RandomMethod` is safe.

[This page](http://www.digdes.com/art/118-contract-programming-net) has a good explanation about class invariants.

Comment: Thanks mate. Adding a `ContractInvariantMethod` solved the problem :)